# How to get the Id of an EmailMessage after sending a SingleEmailMessage with Messaging.SendEmail()?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage, emailmessage

Is there any way to easily retrieve the Id of EmailMessage records after sending them via Messaging.SendEmail()?

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage m = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
m.setToAddresses( new String[]{'heim@elastify.eu'} );
m.setSubject(     'test'  ); 
m.setHtmlBody(    '...' );
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { m });
```

Now how can I get the Id(s) of EmailMessage(s) generated as a result of the sending?

Comment: Messaging.SendEmailResult[] returns `getErrors()` and `isSuccess()` only.

Comment: @SantanuBoral Yes, I've seen that. Now it can be really hard to determine the correct Email via SOQL. Only thing I figure is to query for the newest email sent by the current user. But it feels bad. Also I'm not sure if Messaging.SendEmail might be an asynchronous process.

Comment: Your project sounds really interesting, based on all the questions you've been asking recently.

Comment: @sfdcfox - really not a big thing - only sending/receiving some emails with attachments but having the need to do it "right".

Answer (score 6):

You can't get the `Id` on the same transaction because the email messages are sent **after** the transaction succeeds. See items 19 and 20 on the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):

> 19. Commits all DML operations to the database.
> 20. Executes post-commit logic, such as sending email.

Email messages are then generated after the final commit. I think you can consider the send process as async, and the method call on Apex just as a confirmation of what the platform will attempt to deliver on said process.

---

What you can do is write a trigger on the `EmailMessage` object. You'll definitely get the Id there, and the relationship to the related object.