# Outbound Email Message empty Attachment Related List

Tags: email, data, automation, salesforce-classic

When sending an email, the person receiving it gets both the body text and the attachment being sent out along with it. So it sends out correctly.

When I go into the activity history related list and click on the Outbound Email Message record there is no Attachment in the related list only the body text that was sent out.

Is this how it's supposed to work? Is there a way to view the body text and attachments that were sent out in the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMessageObj = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

Then Sadly, yeah :(

There was a similar thread here:
[Why SingleEmailMessage.setFileAttachments() does not create visible attachments in the Activity Tab in Lightning Experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224643/why-singleemailmessage-setfileattachments-does-not-create-visible-attachments)

Hope this helps!!