# How to send Case Emails to Users via Apex

Tags: governorlimits, limits, singleemailmessage, email2case

**Note:** this question has been significantly edited after I discovered a new, more immediate issue with this scenario.

My use case:

1. A Case may be created via Internal User, Community User, or Email-to-case.
2. The Case will have 1 or more CaseContactRoles which relate a Community User to the case via their Contact record.
3. There is a custom object with a lookup to Case.  When new records are created that relate to a case, notify all related Community Users via email.  Only case contacts who are Community Users will be notified, to avoid hitting apex email limits.
4. The notification emails will use the email-to-case address as the From address;  users should be able to reply to the notification email to add EmailMessage records to the case.

The notification emails (#3) are sent via an Apex trigger on the related object, using SingleEmailMessage.  In order to satisfy requirement 4, I am using `.setWhatId(caseId)` and `.setSaveAsActivity(true)`.  Beside creating a Task record, this causes an `EmailMessage` record to be created for the outbound email, with its `ParentId` set to the case; any replies to the email are handled automatically by Salesforce and linked to the case.  This works fine (for contacts, see below), and the side effect is that the outbound notification email appears in the Emails related list on the case.

In order to avoid hitting email limits, I need to use `.setTargetObjectId(userId)`, **however**, using this in conjunction with `.setSaveAsActivity(true)` throws the error:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_SAVE_AS_ACTIVITY_FLAG, saveAsActivity must be false when sending mail to users.

I need `.setTargetObjectId(userId)` to avoid limits, and I need `.setSaveAsActivity(true)` to generate `EmailMessage` records which link to the case.

I've considered creating the EmailMessage records myself, however, I believe that MessageId and/or ThreadId are needed by the EmailToCase processor to associate replies to the original case, and [there is no way to get the MessageId for an email sent via apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/224649/149), so I would not be able to set those fields.

Have I overlooked anything?  Specifically:

- Is there a way to allow replies to the outbound emails to correctly be associated to the case without using `.setSaveAsActivity(true)` to create `EmailMessage` records?
- Is there some other way to make the system generate `EmailMessage` records for `SingleEmailMessage` emails?

Comment: i believe that E2C Threading using headers does a query on EmailMessage object, filtering by `MessageId` in order to know what Case the inbound email belongs to. So, I'd imagine the answer to question 1 is NO

Comment: Is this for a specific email address or several? Are you using [apex email service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm) at all?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves No custom Apex Email Service; I'm just using Email2Case.  Notification emails (#4 above) are sent via Apex from the E2C inbound email address;  If that email generates an EmailMessage with ParentId = <caseId>, any reply to the outbound email is automatically associated to the case by E2C via the `MessageIdentifier` and/or `ThreadIdentifier` fields. (The docs are not clear which is used, but empirically it works perfectly).  I just cannot generate the EmailMessage without using `setSaveAsActivity`, as outlined above.